# Trying to build LSTM : Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1)

Tags: keras, lstm, sequential

I am trying to build a LSTM but getting an error with the size of my input. Here's my code :

```
from keras.layers import LSTM

time_steps = 10
x_train_LSTM = X_train[:, None, :]
x_test_LSTM = X_test[:, None, :]

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4,activation='relu', input_shape=(time_steps, 21)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x_train_LSTM, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=256, verbose=2)

y_pred = model.predict(x_test_LSTM)

cm=confusion_matrix(Y_test, y_pred)
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
sns.heatmap(cm,annot=True,linewidth=0.5,cmap='Blues',fmt=".0f",ax=ax,xticklabels=target_names, yticklabels=target_names)

# Classification Report
class_report = classification_report(Y_test, y_pred)
print("Classification Report:\n", class_report)
```

The error is the following:

```
Input 0 of layer sequential_6 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 21)
```

My input has 22+ rows and X has 21 features.

What should I change?

I expected that the input was correct but everything I'm trying returns an error.